# subtracting and dividing all the elements of the list in python

Tags: python

A very basic question.. but I always do the bad implementation of this.

I have a list of ints.

And then I have a int "k" and "j"

I want to do something like this:

```
for ele in foo_list:
   ele = (ele - k) / j
```

Is there a pythonic syntactic sugar to make this thing look pretty .
Also, i have a bad feeling like this is a very bad way and prone to bugs..

Is it safe to do an operation

```
 val = function(val)
```

so you take an input and your output is saved to input.. Can this method become "Gotcha" at some point? or is it safe to do these kind of operations?
Thanks

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should be

```
foo_list = [ (ele - k) / j for ele in foo_list]
```

Edit: To answer your second question, `val = f(val)` is fine. But the way you were trying to use it doesn't work: `ele` isn't a pointer to the element in the list, it's a variable name which happens to point to that element. When you assign something else to it, you're making that variable name point somewhere else: you're NOT writing into the location it points to.

Comment: This is a [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) - it's also worth noting that doing ``x = f(x)`` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @Lattyware: alrighty.. :) Thanks a lot.. Python gotchas can be hard to figure out. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: Let's please say "refer to" or "name" rather than "point to". We're not really dealing with machine addresses (or even virtualized ones) here.

Comment: @Karl: blimey, split some hairs why don't you? Good grief. Did I say anything about addresses?

Answer (score 1):

Or map as usual:

```
foo_list = map(lambda ele: (ele-k)/j,foo_list)
```

Comment: Just to note, wherever you need to use ``lambda`` ``map()`` is going to be slower, and (more importantly) harder to read, so stick to list comps (or generator/dict/set comps as needed). ``map()`` is generally only useful for really simple things.

Comment: Yes, in fact I love to use map together with the operator module